# Create a verified publisher domain DNS record not verifying on pub.dev

Tags: flutter, github-pages, open-source

I am creating a publisher on pub.dev and my domain is engzeeshanali.github.io which is a GitHub page.
Now they asked to verify the domain through Google Search Console.

[image]

I have verified the ownership on Google Search Console and it has been more than 48 hours and I got the email from Google that verification is completed and now the site monitoring is enabled.

[image]

But still getting the same error that

> Error
> Verification unsuccessful. To create the verified publisher engzeeshanali.github.io, you must verify ownership of the domain engzeeshanali.github.io in the Google Search Console.
> You must verify the domain property with a DNS record — verifying a URL prefix property or being a collaborator on a property that someone else has verified is not sufficient.
> Open Google Search Console.Once you have completed the verification step in Google Search Console, close this dialog and re-initiate the publisher creation step by clicking create publisher again.